# Javascript: function's variables visibility

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and want to test the following code:

```
var name1 = "global";

function userobject(){
    this.name1 = "local";
}
function func() {
    alert(name1);
}

var myobject=new userobject();
func();
func.call(myobject);
```

In my understanding, at first call to func, the alert("global") should be invoked,
but on the second call, func.call(myobject), the alert("local") should be invoked,

but in fact in both cases "global" text is shown. 
I thought, that when executing, when interpreter sees the variable name, it tryes to identify it in it locally, and if it can't find it there it will search it in the parent.
In my case I thought due to the func.call(myobject), the parent is the myobject, and the function should use it's name1 variable, which is defined as "local".

Please correctly where I am wrong in understanding this things?

Comment: `this.name1` is not a local variable, but a *property* of `myobject`. You can't access it like a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the interpreter can't find the `name1` in scope, it begins to search for it in the outer-scope and eventually into the global namespace if one cannot be found. There are no implicit references to `this` so `name1` is always the global variable and never any local object properties. If you had explicitly access the property then your code would work as expected:

```
function func() {
    alert( this.name1 );
}
```

Your `call` method *does* put `this` in scope but it does not change what local variables refer to. You can have a variable with the same name of a global object property but they won't be the same thing.

Comment: If I am correct, when function is called, the interpreter creates the activation object and puts as properties to that object the local variables and function arguments. And this is what scope is, isn't it? if simply calling func() then it means that the global scope is identified by window object. I thought that by calling function using func.call, that object is changed to myobject..

Comment: @maximus No, the local variables of a function are not properties of an object. And a scope is only defined by a function. If there is a function, that function has a scope.